# jQuery .on('load') is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying test for when an image is loaded so I can change the opacity and fade it in, and I want to do this to all images with the `.hphoto` class.

This is how I'm attempting it with jQuery:

```
function handle_photoloads() {
    $(".hphoto").each(function (i,obj) {
        console.log("Yo");
        if ($(obj).complete) {
            console.log("1");
            $(obj).css('opacity','1');
        } else {
            console.log("incomplete");
            $(obj).on('load',function () {
                console.log("2");
                $(obj).css('opacity','1');
            });
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    handle_photoloads();
});
```

The outputs I get are "Yo" and "incomplete", and I get one of each output for the amount of `.hphoto` objects I have, so something is working. Why is the load handler not being triggered as expected?

Comment: are the `.hphoto`s added dynamically?

Comment: Do jQuery objects have a `complete` property? What type are the `.hphoto` elements? Very few elements emit `load` events.

Comment: Why don't you use the .ready() event also on the hphotos?

https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @matan7890: What do you mean? Eric *is* using jQuery's `ready` event. (`img` elements don't have a `ready` event, there's just one DOM-wide one that jQuery provides.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, I read by mistake that the ready event is when the something is "ready" (in my mind = loaded)... I need to get some sleep...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is a problem:

```
if ($(obj).complete) {
```

You're looking for a `complete` property on the jQuery object, not the DOM element it wraps. Since `obj` refers to the DOM element, the simplest thing is:

```
if (obj.complete) {              // Where `obj` refers to the DOM element
```

Otherwise, use `prop`, but you wouldn't normally use it when you're wrapping something you know is an element:

```
if ($(obj).prop("complete")) {   // Where `obj` refers to the DOM element
```

---

**However**, note that checking for the `complete` flag and then adding a handler has a ***small*** chance of missing the event. JavaScript in browsers has only one UI thread, but the *browser* is not single-threaded. This is a perfectly valid sequence of events:

1. The JavaScript interpreter evaluates `$(obj).prop("complete")` and gets back the value `false`.
2. The browser's image loading code, running on a different thread, sees that it has finished loading that image and checks to see if there are any event handlers registered for the `load` event; not seeing any, it doesn't add any handler callback for when the UI thread is next able to process the pending calls queue.
3. The JavaScript interpreter hooks the `load` event on the image.

The odds are very low, but it can happen.

If you're worried about it, hook the handler *first*, then check `complete` and, if it's set, call your handler and unregister it. In a rare converse of the above, you might get *two* calls rather than one (because the event occurred after you hooked the handler but before you checked `complete`), but "sometimes two" is better than "sometimes zero." :-)

jQuery's subtly-named `one` function can be useful in this context:

```
function handle_photoloads() {
    $(".hphoto").each(function (i,obj) {
        var photo = $(obj);            // Or = $(this), which would be more common
        console.log("Yo");
        photo.one("load", function() { // Note `one`, not `on`
            photo.css('opacity','1');
        });
        if (photo.prop("complete")) {
            photo.trigger("load");
        }
    });
}
```

`one` removes the handler the first time it's called. So we only get one callback, regardless of timing.

(In the above, instead of `if (photo.prop("complete"))`, you could do `if (photo[0].complete)`)

Comment: Is this related with the "Caveats of the load event when used with images" described on this jQuery page? http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: @danbal: Yeah, I'm not 100% sure that the first and fourth bullets in that list are quite accurate. I suspect the issues related to the first and fourth bullets are simply down to timing: If your code is running after the browser has created the `img` element (as it must be, to hook an event on it) and that `img` element's `src` is set, you have to assume that the `load` event may have *already* been fired. :-) I'm reasonably certain that if you get an `img` element that doesn't yet have a `src`, hook `load`, and set the `src`, you'll see the event reliably (or the `error` event, of course).

Comment: It turns out I wasn't paying attention to the rest of my page. The "images" I was trying to handle are actually div elements with background images set. I'm marking this as the solution though, because you correctly pointed out some logic errors in that code excerpt that would otherwise have been overlooked. Thanks!

Comment: @EricDubé: LOL! Oh, that's funny (we've all done it).